# webapi owin use token and cookie

Tags: angularjs, cookies, asp.net-web-api, owin, bearer-token

I have two main projects in my Web application:

1. WebApi project as back-end to serve authentication and authorization for the Web project,using OWIN 2 with bearer tokens.
2. Web project uses Angularjs.

The Web project works as expected(authentication and authorization are working)

Method: store token to localstorage, and send it using interceptors each request.

Now I want to add authentication and authorization to the the WebApi project,which would serve other modules like Hangfire,Elmah and Help pages.
I added the same login logic, which works(Authorizing) and then redirect to Dashboard page(using Angularjs) which works.

But going to any other page(one of the mentioned modules) don't work.By not working: The user from the Owin context always null/empty.(see code)

For my understanding, I need somehow to send the token with each request which doesn't happen here.

Questions:

1. How can I achieve that(sending/getting the token)?

   If cookie is the only/better approach ↴
2. How can I integrate cookie for project 1 and token for project 2?(Tried to use cookies, but it seems I'm doing it wrong, or does it work simultaneously with bearer tokens?)

Code:

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {

        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
        RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
    };

    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    app.UseHangfire(hangfireConfig =>
    {
        config.UseAuthorizationFilters(
            new AuthorizationFilter { Users = "admin, superuser", Roles = "advanced" },
            new ClaimsBasedAuthorizationFilter("name", "value")
        );

        hangfireConfig.UseSqlServerStorage("Context");
        hangfireConfig.UseServer();
    });
}
```

I tried for testing purposes:

```cs
public class HFAuthorizationFilter : Hangfire.Dashboard.IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
    {
        var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironment);

        if (context.Authentication.User == null)
            return false;//Always null

        return context.Authentication.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "SuperAdmin")
            || context.Authentication.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin");
    }
}
```

and in Configuration:

```cs
app.UseHangfire(hangfireConfig =>
{
    hangfireConfig.UseAuthorizationFilters(
        new HFAuthorizationFilter()
    );

    hangfireConfig.UseSqlServerStorage("Context");
    hangfireConfig.UseServer();
});
```

Potential duplicate:
[Passing and verifying the OWIN Bearer token in Query String in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925367/passing-and-verifying-the-owin-bearer-token-in-query-string-in-webapi?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly, you are looking to implement token generation in one api and use the same token in other api. if that is the case then you need master api to be the token generator and child or dependent api to consume the token. Please find master and child API config for oauth
Master API config:

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //configure OAuth using owin framework
            var oAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
                Provider = new KatanaAuthorizationServerProvider()

            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
```

Child API config:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
```

Comment: It's old, but I don't think you understood correctly. There are some requests that I don't initiate or can't control but I need to be able to pass the token.