# How to make a HTML 5 video tag, bearer authenticated with a WebAPI?

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a HTML 5 video tag pointing to my ASP.NET WebAPI which requires bearer authentication, most of my requests towards my API look like that:

```
GET http://localhost:29080/api/v1/users/me HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:29080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Authorization: Bearer c66b36fe-fcc1-49da-9b42-dac783768a06
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8
```

Since the application is hosted on a different port (and eventually a different address) it is subject to CORS. I've already setup my WebAPI to be compliant:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

Sadly my HTML 5 video tag does not seem work out with that setup.

```
<video 
      crossorigin="use-credentials"
      src="http://localhost:29080/api/v1/entities/470/presentation-video">
```

I end up with:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:29080/api/v1/entities/470/presentation-video: 
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must 
not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. 
Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

In addition to the:

```
GET http://localhost:29080/api/v1/entities/470/presentation-video 401 (Unauthorized)
```

I really don't know what to think of, I've read somewhere that the bearer could be passed as query string like

But I could not manage to make it work...

Any idea?

Comment: The error says that since you ask crossOrigin credentials, allow wildcard header in the response is invalid. Maybe you'd get luckier with anonymous, but I don't know how it relates to your bearer thing.

Comment: @Kaiido cause in my other requests, there is a header to allow auth: Authorization: Bearer c66b36fe-fcc1-49da-9b42-dac783768a06

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484982/asp-net-web-api-how-to-pass-an-access-token-oauth-2-0-using-url-parameter not sure if it's gonna lead me somewhere

Comment: @Kaiido says 401 unauthorized =/

Comment: @Kaiido the thing is that the <video> tag does not allow you to specify headers... =/

Comment: No, I have to admit I am not entirely certain how to do it, but from my understanding, you'd have to request the credentials separately, in the form of a cookie, then `use-credentials` should take care of providing these credentials along the requests. How it is done exactly, I'm not sure.

Comment: that's what I thought to, actually another trickery is to pass as a query string and modify the webapi to transform the query string into the appropriate header in the begin request handler in the global.asax...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179778/discussion-between-kaiido-and-ehouarn-perret).

Comment: Follow-up: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179778/discussion-between-kaiido-and-ehouarn-perret

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright so the solution for me was:

In my front-end app:

```
<video controls crossorigin="anonymous" src="..." </video>
```

and setup the `src` of my video such as (example):  `http://localhost:29080/api/v1/entities/470/presentation-video?access_token=c66b36fe-fcc1-49da-9b42-dac783768a06`

Since the WebAPI does not really check query parameters (even though they should...) we need a way to convert the `access_token` to a header when receiving it such as described in that answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25525470/4636721

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.QueryString.HasValue)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization")))
            {
                var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.Request.QueryString.Value);
                string token = queryString.Get("access_token");

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                {
                    context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new[] { string.Format("Bearer {0}", token) });
                }
            }
        }

        await next.Invoke();
    });
    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
}
```